# Use-site targeted annotations are not accessible with Kotlin reflection

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I use the annotation site target `@get` that confused me for a while.

```
class GetSiteTarget1(@get:Annotation val value: Int = 1);
class GetSiteTarget2 {
    val value = 1
        @Annotation get () {
            return field;
        }
};
```

both classes above with different result:

```
GetSiteTarget1::value.getter.annotations; // not has @Annotation
GetSiteTarget1::value.getter.javaMethod!!.annotations // has @Annotation

GetSiteTarget2::value.getter.annotations; // has @Annotation
GetSiteTarget2::value.getter.javaMethod!!.annotations // has @Annotation
```

**AND** both class has annotated with `@Annotation`:

```
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #10() // @Annotation
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I would report it at [Kotlin (KT) | YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) if there isn't already an issue for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use-site targeted annotations are not visible in kotlin-reflect yet. This is a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10837.

Comment: sir. I have saw it. the bug is reported in Jan, why didn't fix it yet?

Comment: The bug is not fixed yet because it has not been recognized as a major issue and there's a relatively simple workaround.

Comment: thanks very much. "there's a relatively simple workaround" - what are you mean is using java `javaMethod.annotations`?